# How to resolve javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake exception

Tags: java, api, rest, server

I am working on java 7 with TestNG rest assured framework and testing some server calls. Lately faced some exception while running my test. It is ignoring my test and throw below exception javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:Remote host terminated the handshake.
I have tried to insert server certificate into java charsets, but it did not help at all.
Also provided TLSv1.3,TLSv1.2 to a protocol still not seeing results. What would be the possible causes and how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Understand the root of the problem and resolve it.

Comment: What happens if you use a modern, supported version of java? Does it work?

Comment: I tried to switch to java 8 didn't noticed any differences

Comment: How about Java 17?